# Why is my App Engine app hitting the Stackdriver Logging 256KB limit?

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine-python, google-cloud-stackdriver

I'm migrating a Python 2  App Engine Standard app to the new Python 3 Standard runtime, which is [very different](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/python-differences#app_engine_apis). One big difference is that you use Google Cloud APIs explicitly, including [Stackdriver Logging](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/). I'm using [google-cloud-logging](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/logging/)'s [App Engine Handler](https://googleapis.dev/python/logging/latest/handlers-app-engine.html) and configuring it to correlate logs with HTTP requests:

```py
import google.cloud.logging
logging_client = google.cloud.logging.Client()

from google.cloud.logging.handlers import AppEngineHandler, setup_logging
setup_logging(AppEngineHandler(logging_client, name='stdout'))
```

This works great!...except it hits [a 256KB log entry limit](https://cloud.google.com/logging/quotas#log-limits) and crashes somewhat regularly. Stack trace below. This happens in long-running background requests that do a fair amount of work, but when I count the total amount of logged text (including string timestamps) in requests that crash, it only averages 5-15KB or so, far smaller than 256KB. (Yes, the docs warn [*This approximate limit is based on internal data sizes*](https://cloud.google.com/logging/quotas#log-limits), but it's hard to believe that overhead is 15-50x.)

The App Engine Handler defaults to [`BackgroundThreadTransport`](https://googleapis.dev/python/logging/latest/transports-thread.html). I've tried lowering its `batch_size` from 10 (the default) to 1, and switching to [`SyncTransport`](https://googleapis.dev/python/logging/latest/transports-sync.html), but no luck.

Any idea what I'm missing? Thank you in advance!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/logging/handlers/transports/background_thread.py", line 123, in _safely_commit_batch
    batch.commit()
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/logging/logger.py", line 383, in commit
    client.logging_api.write_entries(entries, **kwargs)
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/logging/_gapic.py", line 126, in write_entries
    partial_success=partial_success,
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/logging_v2/gapic/logging_service_v2_client.py", line 477, in write_log_entries
    request, retry=retry, timeout=timeout, metadata=metadata
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/gapic_v1/method.py", line 143, in __call__
    return wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", line 277, in retry_wrapped_func
    on_error=on_error,
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", line 182, in retry_target
    return target()
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/timeout.py", line 214, in func_with_timeout
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 59, in error_remapped_callable
    six.raise_from(exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc), exc)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
google.api_core.exceptions.InvalidArgument: 400 Log entry with size 258.3K exceeds maximum size of 256.0K
```

Comment: You are exceeding the maximum size of a Stackdriver entry. You will need to make each request that you make to Stackdriver smaller (less than 256 KB). Since you do not show you code and the logging data being generated for Stackdriver, I cannot tell you what to change.

Comment: thanks! right, i understand that, but i'm not making requests to Stackdriver explicitly. i'm using `google.cloud.logging.handlers.AppEngineHandler`, as described in the question, and then just `logging.info(...)` etc calls that accumulate only 5-15KB of text max per HTTP request.

Comment: Where in your question is an example of `logging.info(...)`? Show something that we can help you with.

Comment: agreed! isolated reproducible test cases are definitely ideal. they're not always realistic, though, and i don't have one here. i haven't yet reproduced this outside of production, possibly because it's due to an interaction _across_ HTTP requests. that could explain how it's accumulating so much data per Stackdriver request, beyond any single HTTP request's logs. i don't know though. i'm hoping for insights here from anyone familiar with `google.cloud.logging` and the `AppEngineHandler` i'm using here.

Answer (score 1):

The [Stackdriver Log Entry Size](https://cloud.google.com/logging/quotas) constitutes a hard limit, which has already been extended from 100KB to 256KB (See posts on [Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/141996314) and [Release Notes](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/release-notes#April_23_2019)).

As a workaround you may explore logging in multiple stages to avoid this limitation error. You could **break an individual entry into multiple entries** and log it as such.

Additionally, you could **store the full size logs from your application directly on Cloud Storage and only send to Stackdriver part of the logs**, enough to allow you to know if you are interested in the full log line or not. Generally, it would be better if you could only store minimal information in Stackdriver and use a different storage system (a bucket in cloud storage, a spanner or a CloudSQL db,  or any other SQL or no-SQL database) to store more detailed information, and then link the two with a UUID.

Moreover, to facilitate the situation, I recommend you to **exclude unnecessary logs** in order to minimize the size of the file. (See [Log Exclusions](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/exclusions) and [Preventing Log Waste](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/preventing-log-waste-with-stackdriver-logging)). You can also [**export these excluded log entries**](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/exclusions#export-exclusions) before, so that you don't permanently lose them.

I hope you find this information useful.

Comment: thank you for the reply! i appreciate it. i'm definitely aware of all of this, though. as mentioned, i'm using `google.cloud.logging.handlers.AppEngineHandler`, not making requests to Stackdriver explicitly, so i don't have visibility or control into the log entries it sends.  
  
more importantly,  i'm only logging ~5-15KB of text maximum per HTTP request, nowhere near 256KB, so i suspect `AppEngineHandler` is collecting logs across multiple HTTP requests. i haven't found a way to control or disable that.